# Cannot update Managed Package ValidationRule

Tags: validation-rule, tooling-api

I built a Validation Rule for a Managed Package object in my org (so this new rule is not part of the managed package). When I got to update that object's Metadata "Active" field, I get this error:

```
'INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY': 'In field: fullName - no ValidationRule named Scenario__c.SFSSDupeCatcher__PersonAccount_Contact_Filtertype found'
```

My code is simply

```
 if metadata['active'] is True:
     metadata['active'] = False
     self.update(id, {'Metadata': metadata})
```

Comment: Is `SFSSDupeCatcher__` the managed package namespace? If so, you might need to exclude it to reference your custom validation rule.